# Getting difference between 2 pixels and handling the overflow error

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to find the difference between 2 pixels, `p` and `q` of the same image. Here is what I do:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("coin.png",0)

diff = np.absolute(img[0][0] - img[1][45])
```

This results in :

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
```

Why does this warning occur? The `dtype` of image is `uint8`. How could I find the difference between two pixels?

Also, why is the result of the following 2 equations different?

```
np.absolute(img[0][0] - img[1][45])
# results in 166
```

and

```
np.absolute(img[1][45] - img[0][0])
# results in 90
```

What is happening here? Isn't it the normal subtraction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed already, the image is loaded as 1-byte unsigned integer `uint8`.

So overflow may happen - which is the same reason why your two equations printing absolute value differ.

You can simply cast to `int` to fix the issue.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([121], dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.asarray([93], dtype=np.uint8)

print(abs(a - b))  # prints [28]
print(abs(b - a))  # prints [228]

a = a.astype(int)
b = b.astype(int)

print(abs(a - b))  # prints [28]
print(abs(b - a))  # prints [28]
```

Comment: I have a follow up question for the same, is the operation done on np.uint8 is performed on bitwise level? which causes absolute to give different value when operands are interchanged? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid overflow while computing absolute difference by subtracting a smaller number from a larger number:

```
res = np.maximum(x,y) - np.minimum(x,y)
```